# XML dtd CDATA declaration clarifaction

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

After reading I have found that you cannot set an element to contain `CDATA` by default using a DTD document. In this case could you explain what:

```
<!ELEMENT element-name (#CDATA)>
```

Does when put into a relevant DTD document. I know this is probably a simple question but I cannot find the answer. Also is there an alternative to having to write:

```
<element-name><![CDATA[Some unparsed data]></element-name>
```

Using XML schema?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I might be completely wrong, but isn't CDATA allowed wherever escaped text is, and vice versa? (Also, who uses DTDs anyway? XSD or RelaxNG schemas are much more expressive.)

Comment: If you try it, you'll see that what `<!ELEMENT element-name (#CDATA)>` does in a DTD is produce a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDATA means *Character Data*. It's not the same thing as [CDATA Section](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect). A *content model* for an *element* can't contain `(#CDATA)`, but `(#PCDATA)`, which means *Parsed* Character Data. Enclosing text inside a *CDATA Section* will allow it to be kept unparsed in the XML instance.

In your DTD you must use:

```
<!ELEMENT element-name (#PCDATA)>
```

And you can have plain text, escaped special chars *and CDATA sections* in that element. There is no mechanism to automatically set a CDATA section in an element.

If you are generating or *transforming* a document (using XSLT), you can, during the transformation, generate CDATA sections as the contents of the elements you are generating.